# Ho to get a specific instance of a custom Blazor Component

Tags: blazor

Coming from asp.net webforms I have always some doubts how to achieve some task in Blazor, not having a unique ID that references controls, or component.

Let say I have a custom component called MyCard (a simple bootstrap card) that exposes a Visible property:

```
<div class="card mb-3 @display" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        @ChildContent
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    string display = "";

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private bool _visible = true;
    [Parameter]
    public bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return _visible;
        }
        set
        {
            _visible = value;
            display = value ? "" : "d-none";
        }
    }

}
```

And then I use more than one on a page:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<MyCard Visible="@hidetoggles[0]">First Card</MyCard>

<MyCard Visible="@hidetoggles[1]">Second Card</MyCard>

<MyCard Visible="@hidetoggles[2]">Third Card</MyCard>

<button @onclick="Hide">Hide the 2nd card</button>

@code
{
    bool[] hidetoggles = new bool[] { true, true, true };

    void Hide()
    {
        hidetoggles[1] = false;
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant method to set the property of a specific instance (eg. the second) instead what I did?

Could an ID property in MyCard be useful?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoting [Capture references to components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#capture-references-to-components) docs:

> Component references provide a way to reference a component instance so that you can issue commands to that instance, such as **Show** or **Reset**. To capture a component reference:
>
> - Add an `@ref` attribute to the child component.
> - Define a field with the same type as the child component.

For your code:

**MyCard.razor:**

```
<div class="card mb-3 @display" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        @ChildContent
    </div>
</div>
    
@code {
    string display = "";

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    public void setVisible(bool visible)
    {
        if(visible)
        {
            display = "";
        }
        else
        {
            display = "d-none";
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.razor:**

```
<MyCard @ref="MyCardControl1">First Card</MyCard>
<button @onclick="Hide">Hide card</button>
@code{

    MyCard MyCardControl1;

    private void Hide()
    {
        MyCardControl1.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

More info at [Blazor Binding, Events and Parameters](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/25).

Comment: @dani herrera - Your demo is better :)

Comment: thanks, but is almost the same. The main concept is `@ref` 

Comment: Yeah the basic point is people won't understand @ref until you explain it to them. Then they are like "ohhhh"

Comment: And the tragic is that I bought Michael's book :-) bad memory!! thx

Comment: @Michael Washington, please read the quote you display in your answer: "issue commands to that instance, such as Show or Reset". Visible is a Component Parameter Property, not a command (method), and you shouldn't set its value the way you do. This is the warning issued by the compiler when you do that: 'Component parameter 'Visible' should not be set outside of its component.' Yes, right now, its a warning, and may be considered an error in the future when Blazor matured.

Comment: @enet - Yes it is not recommended to use this to show and hide DOM events. So the next recommendation would be to wrap the element in a f statement to control the visibility. However, ref would stay the same :)

Comment: No, you're wrong. Once again, you shouldn't set up a component parameter like this: MyCardControl1.Visible = false; Why don't you create the sample code and see the warning issued by the compiler ?

Comment: @enet - I updated the code sample to remove compiler warnings

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is just hide the card when it is clicked then you can do as below.

***MyCard.razor***

```
<div style="@Display" @onclick="Hide">
    This is CardNumber-@CardNumber
</div>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public int CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string Display{ get; set; }

    public void Hide()
    {
        //By using this keyword you can access the clicked instance. ex: this.CardNumber
        Display = "display:none";
    }
}
```

***Index.razor***

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
<MyCard CardNumber="i" />
}
```